# How to block chrome extension from open new tab?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension

How to block Ghostery extension from open new tab after installation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just edited the question to a better explanation about the scenario. Can someone now understand how it works?

Comment: @osfresia it's against site rules to edit other user's questions to change their meaning, if you want ask a new question including the additional information specific to your case.

Comment: @bad_coder I did not changed the meaning, just added a scenario to better explain the outcome necessary and a useful "tryout" case.

Comment: @osfresia it is advisable in these cases to ask a new question, it will have much better chances of getting an answer. Also, *"adding an example (or scenario)"* to another poster's question is not considered a good practice because the OP might have intended something different with their question - it's also very difficult for reviewers to evaluate such changes.